# Read Yahoo/Gmail Email using Selenium Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I want to read some emails from Yahoo using Protractor (mainly forgot password, user invitations etc). I have tried using Mail-Listener4 and Mail-Listener2 but maybe I am doing something wrong.

One way is that I simulate reading of emails but that would require more time for my E2E. So, I want to use Mail-Listener to read these emails.

Is there any sample working code that I can use in order to fetch my desired emails from Yahoo? I am using Protractor version 6.13.6

Thanks

Comment: what if you use other mail service that don't require registration, user verification, recaptcha etc? can this work for, if so I can provide you with a code. For example mailsac.com... you can just generate random address like qwerty@mailsac.com and access it without password

Comment: I can surely look into it since I am only using this for E2E purposes.